# why is charset=UTF8 specified in the headers when serving binary files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, content-type

I've got`Content-Type:image/png;charset=UTF-8` in my headers. I'm setting the contentType to `image/png`, in this case, which is correct for the file being returned. I suspect this has something to do with the default type being json. `charset=UTF-8` is being added regardless of what I set the `contentType` to

```
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType( MediaType.parseMediaType( mimeType.getType().toString() ) )
            .lastModified( path.toFile().lastModified() )
            .cacheControl( CacheControl.maxAge( 1, TimeUnit.DAYS ).cachePrivate() )
            .body( resource );
```

could this actually cause a problem? how can I fix it?

Comment: "I'm setting the contentType, and it's otherwise correct." is not clear

Comment: @davidhxxx updated

Comment: and if you don't set the contentType in your request header, what is the  problem ?

Comment: @davidhxxx it's returning `Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8` regardless of the actual content type

Comment: What does `mimetype` contain exactly?